# HTMLAgilityPack - Detecting a blank table?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using c# with htmlagilitypack.  Everything works fine except when the table I'm looking for contains no rows.  I'm trying to read only the data from the 1st table on the page.  The problem is if the first table contains no rows, the htmlagilitypack seems to jump down to the 2nd table for some reason.

The html I'm trying to read looks something like this:

```
<table class='stats'>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'>This is the 1st table</td>
    <tr>
      <td>Column A</td>
      <td>Column B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value A</td>
      <td>Value B</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class='stats'>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'>This is the 2nd table</td>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 111</td>
      <td>Value 222</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I then retrieve the 1st table's values using the following line:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in root.SelectNodes("//table[@class='stats']/tr[position() > 2]/td"))
```

How do I ensure the data I'm grabbing is only from the 1st table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could ensure that you only select the first matching table by using a position index `[1]` after the table selector.

Try the following:

```
"//table[@class='stats'][1]/tr[position()>2]/td"
```

If the first table has no rows, then you will get `null` back so you should check for that before iterating in the `foreach`.

For example you might want to do the following:

```
var elements = root.SelectNodes("//table[@class='stats'][1]/tr[position()>2]/td");
if (elements != null)
{
  foreach (HtmlNode node in elements)
  {
    // process the td node
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, this didn't work.  It seems to be a problem with no table id being specified.

Comment: Can you provide an example HTML that demonstrates the problem? I tested using the sample from your question and removed the <tr>s from the first table and got null for the SelectNodes, which is what I understood you need.

Comment: The actual code is longer than the total allowable characters here, so here's the page I'm trying to read.  It's the first table with a "class='statstable'", about halfway down the page.  This 1st table (called "Season Stats") contains 2 header rows but no data rows, which is where I'm running into my issue.  I need to be able to determine when there are no data rows present: http://www.rotoworld.com/player/mlb/6633/luis-jimenez  <br/> Thanks again.

Comment: @user1070194, I have taken a quick look at the URL you provided and all I can say is that the HTML is extremely hostile! The reason that you cannot find an appropriate xpath query is that it seems that HAP is becoming confused with all the <th> and <tr> that nest each other and do not have closing tags. Both IE Developer Toolbar and FireBug interpret the resulting DOM differently (though it renders fine).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an id on the table or row which uniquely identifies the table or or and then use the id in the xpath.

Comment: Yeah, I think my issue seems to be due to the fact the tables I'm reading don't have id's associated with them.

Comment: I tried running some tests & realized when I specify "[@class='stats']/tr[position() > 2]", it's returning ALL rows of all "stats" class tables after row 2 of each table.  So, my original example returns 2 rows (Value A|Value B...and Value 111|Value 222).  If there are no rows from table 1, it then simply returns Value 111|Value 222.  It doesn't seem to care which table it came from.  @Chris Taylor

Comment: @goalie35 Why was I downvoted? I think you posted your comment in the wrong answer as your comment was targeted for Chirs Taylor.

Comment: My apologies.  It's been a while since this one, but I don't see a reason as to why this should've been down voted. Perhaps it was in error.